# Any sustainability difference between anionic/cationic/nonionic detergents?

Tags: environmental-impact, pollution, cleaning

Are any of these three types of detergents more or less damaging to manufacture and/or use or dispose of than the others?

I realise these are rather broad classes, but this is usually the only detail one gets on packaging.

Comment: With only a hazy idea of how they're made and how they degrade, I strongly suspect that any difference will be smaller than the difference in quantity used if you occasionally have to wash something a second time because you avoided the most suitable detergent.